How do I ascertain the funding organization of my grant?
I am a graduate student and I applied for a computing grant from here. The grant type I applied for (Explore), allowed graduate students to be PIs, provided the advisor is the co-PI. I would like to add this to my CV. I checked this website and it told me to use the following format -

Current Research (chronological order; most recent one first)
Grant # (PI Name)
Name of Funding Organization (no acronyms)
Amount Awarded
Period of Grant Award
Title of Project
Role on Project (if not the PI)

This looks pretty straightforward except the 'Name of Funding Organization'. As per the website, it seems like a NSF grant due to the following information -

ACCESS is an advanced computing and data resource program supported by the U.S. National Science Foundation (NSF) under the Office of Advanced Cyberinfrastructure awards #2138259, #2138286, #2138307, #2137603 and #2138296.

I am a little wary of adding NSF. Aren't NSF awards only awarded to professors? Perhpas this is one of NSF's side projects?

Also, I was wondering  about the Grant #. The format tells me to put the PI's name in that section, which feels a little weird. I was assuming that all grants have a specific id.

I can’t understand why you are leery of adding NSF here. They fund that program.

I understand that getting NSF grants is quite challenging. Whereas the grant I got was relatively easy and did not require me to have a PhD. I just don't want to write something wrong in my CV.

Full, regular NAF grants are challenging, yes. I’d say “NSF ACCESS grant for computer time” but someone closer to the field can speak up…

Research administrator here.  The line you quoted suggests that the award would be made to an institution as a subcontract.  So ACCESS already has NSF funding and flows it down to an institution to be used for the named graduate student, with a co-PI being someone at the institution who normally has PI rights.  The question is which institution will receive the award.  This has to be indicated in your application somewhere.  Have you reached out to your local research administrator?  This funding will have to be received by your institution, and they have the right to review this application before you submit.  They should help you put it together.  This sort of work relies a lot on local policies and preferences, so reach out to your local research administrator to get proper guidance.  If you don't know who this is, ask your PI.
As an aside, the NSF GRFP is the only fellowship I have ever seen that doesn't need to run through a research administration team beforehand, even though it's still received by the institution and not the individual.  That's because they have an ongoing relationship with institutions on how to administer those fellowships.  When in doubt about how to proceed, reach out to a research administrator as soon as possible so that they have time to help you.
